# In cordova program, how to get NSArray return value in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, nsarray, cordova

I am using cordova(phonegap) framework in my ios program.
In native *.m code, I want to return an Array object to javascript.
The code is :

```
     -(void)getDeviceInfo:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
  {
    unsigned char deviceInfo[30]={0};
    sprintf(deviceInfo,"%s","aaabbb");
    NSData* returnValue=[[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:deviceInfo length:7];
    NSArray *jsResult = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:returnValue,nil];
    CDVPluginResult *result;
    result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:jsResult];
    [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:globalCallbackId]];
  }
```

and in javascript, the code is:

```
  function callGetDeviceInfo() {
            HijackMgrPlugin.getDeviceInfo( deviceInfoResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler,null);
        }


        function deviceInfoResultHandler (result) {
            alert("deviceInfo: \r\n");
            //alert("deviceInfo: \r\n"+result );
        }

        function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
            alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
        }
```

But the alert box didn't appear.
In i change the return value to messageAsString:@"aabb", then the alert box is ok, and 
i can get the return value.
but when it is NSArray value, I can get any result, please help.